# Mission Control behaves unpredictably

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bug, mission-control

When switching applications using **Mission Control**, the application I select moves to the foreground as expected.

However on occasion, it will then **immediately jump back into the background**. This is very annoying. I closed all my other applications but that did not help. Please see this gif for a demo:

[image: Mission Control Unpredictable Behavior]

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug of **Mission Control**, that Apple should fix.

A temporary solution is to:

1. Right click the **Terminal** icon on the **Dock**.
2. Click *Options*.
3. Assigns it to *None* rather than *All Desktops*.

This will however not let the app show up on all desktops any more.